# restful service receives "�" instead of umlaut

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

i call my Rest WebService with the following URL:

... /Service.svc/ChangeMasterData/10?MeasureTypeID=100&LastName=%E4%F6%F6ABC

but instead of getting the correct string "äööABC" in my webservice c# code behind, the string contains only "���ABC".

Any hint where i've forgot something?

--- Additional Information about the C# Code Part ---

IService.cs

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
UriTemplate = "ChangeMasterData/{UserID}?MeasureTypeID&{MeasureTypeID}&LastName={LastName});
```

Service.svc.cs

```
public string ChangeMasterData(string UserID, string MeasureTypeID, string LastName)
{
    // LastName contains "���ABC" instead of "äööABC"
    ...
}
```

Fiddler's HexView from the called URL:

[image]

Comment: How are you observing the contents of `LastName`? What's in the actual request, in terms of bytes? (I'd advise using something like WireShark to see.)

Comment: I actually 'attack to process' with Visual Studio. So i can live debug my code while its running on the webserver. With a Breakpoint directly after my method was called i can see the contents of the variable.

With fiddler i made sure the given url was called.

Comment: Looks like your application is using ASCII encoding. I don't know where you can configure it, but you need to change it to use UTF8.

Comment: @cubrr: Well ASCII can't represent umlauts at all. It looks like it's ISO-8859-1 to me...

Comment: @JonSkeet I stand corrected!

Comment: If we were going to place bets, I'd bet on it actually being CP 1252.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... /Service.svc/ChangeMasterData/10?MeasureTypeID=100&LastName=%E4%F6%F6ABC

Unless you're in the days before RFC 3987 you shouldn't be picking arbitrary encodings to use as the basis for encoding non-ASCII characters in ASCII, so this should be considered either having `LastName=���ABC`, `LastName=��ABC` or perhaps `LastName=���BC` at the end.

> instead of getting the correct string "äööABC"

If that's what you wanted, you should have used `LastName=%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%B6ABC`

Comment: Can you additionally tell me which encoding you are using to get "äööABC" to "%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%B6ABC" ?

Comment: UTF-8 of course. As per RFC 3987 and indeed the fact that it's the only encoding that both covers all characters (making it suitable for use in the 21st century) and matches US-ASCII in the range U+0000 to U+007F (making it suitable for use in URIs). And also URIs are a web technology, why would you use anything other than UTF-8 on the web?

Comment: Sorry, my question was missleading. I meant how did you convert "äööABC" to "%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%B6ABC". But i found it myself in the meantime. I am using encodeURIComponent(...) in JS to encode my Attributes before i send them to the webService :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This part `%E4%F6%F6` looks like it is the URL encoding of `ISO-8859-1` characters, but your webservice probably expects `UTF-8`. Either make sure your string is UTF-8 before doing the URL encoding or make sure the URL encoder understands that you want it to encode as UTF-8.

In Javascript that would be `encodeURIComponent(str)` or `encodeURI(str)`. Javascript `escape` is deprecated in part because it encodes non-ASCII characters in a non standard way.

Comment: Or rather, perform the URL encoding *with* UTF-8. I'm not sure what "change your string to UTF-8" even means...